# std::fstream буферизация или буферизация напрямую

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, fstream

На английской версии stackoverflow наткнулся на такой вопрос:

[std::fstream buffering vs manual buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997131/stdfstream-buffering-vs-manual-buffering-why-10x-gain-with-manual-buffering)

Не очень понимаю, что происходит в методе записи в буфер напрямую? (там этот момент опущен). Я так понимаю, что производится запись напрямую через `streambuf::sputn`
(т.е `stream.rdbuf() ->sputn(buffer, length)`) ?  И зачем в конце вызывается `std::ostream::write`, как и в первом способе? Ведь данные уже напрямую записаны в буфер.

Answer (score 0):

Во втором варианте просто уже есть готовый заполненный буфер, который целиком записывается в файл. Скорее всего, он случайными числами заполнялся, или вручную в цикле, но это неизвестно. В худшем случае, он вообще ничем не заполнен, и в файл записывается мусор.

В первом варианте изначально буфер не заполнен, он передается под управления потока, и уже через интерфейс потока туда записывается множество мелких объектов. Точнее, они записываются в файл через буфер.

Учитывая, что ни способ заполнения буфера во втором варианте, ни размер объекта x в первом варианте не указываются, я бы не стал доверять результатам тестов.